# Cast variadic template type to void, expected ')' before

Tags: c++, c++11, casting, variadic-templates, void

In my code, I use ***variadic template functions*** for the logging mechanism. If `DEBUG` macro is defined, a message is printed; if `DEBUG` is **not** defined, then it should print nothing.

My code:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    inline void LOG_CHAT(){ }
    
    template<typename First, typename ...Rest>
    void LOG_CHAT(First && first, Rest && ...rest){
        std::cout << std::forward<First>(first);
        LOG_CHAT(std::forward<Rest>(rest)...);
    }

#else
    
    template<typename ...Rest>
    void LOG_CHAT(Rest && ...rest){ 
        (void)(rest...);
    }

#endif
```

I would leave the function definition empty, but I do not want to get *"unused parameter"* compiler warning. Therefore, parameter(s) are cast to void to get rid of the compiler warning. However, casting is causing another error that is reproduced below.

> error: expected ')' before 'rest' UNUSED(...rest);
>
> note: in definition of macro 'UNUSED' #define UNUSED(x) (void)(x)

So, my main goal is getting rid of compiler warning, either by casting to `void` or using any other method. But I would be happier if I'd be able to cast it to `void`.

Comment: Which C++ standard version do you use? If the latest (C++17) consider [the `maybe_unused` attribute](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/maybe_unused), or some compiler-specific equivalent.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention c++11 @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: `...rest` should be `rest...`

Comment: @NathanOliver my technique is: move the `...` around until the errors go away

Comment: @eneski Also fix the errors ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can have a `LOG_CHAT` for release with no parameter names, that will inhibit the warning.

```
void LOG_CHAT(Rest && ...)
```